# CSS - Unordered list - class, id not working

Tags: html, css, list, class

I want to modify only some lists, but I can't get it done using class or id.
Here is MWE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    ul#square { list-style: square;}
    ul.square { list-style: square;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <ul id="square">
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Coca Cola</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="square">
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Coca Cola</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Any thoughts?**

Comment: For the second ul, it should be `class='square'`. The first one should work without any issues. [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/P3z5B/).

Comment: Wouldn't using just .square and #square work?

Comment: @harry , couldn't get it. I was tryin to tell OP that using just .classname and #idname will do fine. They are just identifiers so there is no scope of any difference. The styles are applied to elements after all.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: Don't want to hijack this post, that is why I had removed my comment. Basically what I was saying is, using just `.` and `#` would work perfectly fine. But given that other elements (non ul and ol) would not have a need for the `list-style` property, it is not much use removing the tagname from the selector :) But before all that, the error (typo?) in the attribute needed to be corrected.

Comment: I feel stupid. But I tried different combination for more than 20 minutes without succes. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul#square { list-style: square;}
ul.square { list-style: square;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="square">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
<ul class="square">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JSFiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bD9nC/

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/r4z5U/)**

```
<ul id="square">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
<ul class="square"> /* class="square" not sytle*/
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```